# How to pause for loop and wait for user click

Tags: java, for-loop, button, wait

I'm creating a quiz app where randomly generating tasks, but I don't know how to wait for user click in for loop. I tried to do this:

```
    final Integer min=1;
    final Integer max=100;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        button_check3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button_next3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final int x = new Random().nextInt(max - min)+min;
        final int y = new Random().nextInt(max-x - min)+min;
        task3.setText(x + " + " + y + " ="); //set task
        final  int zbroj = x+y;

        button_check3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //check user answer
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button_check3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                button_next3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String user_answer=answer3.getText().toString();
                if (user_answer.equals(zbroj)){
                    check3.setImageResource(R.drawable.true_);
                }
                else {
                    check3.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong_);
                }
            }
        });
        button_next3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //continue for loop
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to:

- generate task
- wait for user click check button and check answer
- wait for user click next button
- continue loop

I want to repeate this five times. **I saw this question before but I didn't find what I need.** Thank you.

Comment: "I saw this question here before but I didn't find what I need." please share what you found and why it didn't work.

Comment: Google for onClickListener().

Comment: You could use a nested while loop. The codes that needs to stop executing when buttons are pressed will be in the 2 nested while loops, while a larger loop keeps executing until a specific condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Doing this is a for-loop is the wrong technique. Ui-systems are event-based where the ui-framework uses a event-loop to process all events. You should redesign your process to use an event-based approch. Like: in the event that the button `button_next3` was clicked, create the new task, set the button `button_next3` invisible and the button `button_check3` visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make next:

```
class LoopActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val button1: Button = findViewById()
    val button2: Button = findViewById()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        setContentView(/*layout*/)
        imitationLoop(false)
    }

    fun imitationLoop(needBreak: Boolean) {
        if (!needBreak) {
            someCode1()
            button1.setOnClickListener {
                button1.setOnClickListener { }
                someCode2()
                button2.setOnClickListener {
                    button2.setOnClickListener { }
                    imitationLoop(/*conditionBreak*/)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun someCode1() {
        //somecode
    }
    fun someCode2() {
        //somecode
    }
}
```

It's recursion. And you need condition for break recursion.
If you want condition for as look (int i=0; i<10; i++):

```
class LoopActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val button1: Button = findViewById()
    val button2: Button = findViewById()
    var i: Int = 0
    var max: Int = 10

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(/*layout*/)
        imitationLoop(false)
    }

    fun imitationLoop(needBreak: Boolean) {
        if (!needBreak) {
            someCode1()
            button1.setOnClickListener {
                button1.setOnClickListener { }
                someCode2()
                button2.setOnClickListener {
                    button2.setOnClickListener { }
                    imitationLoop(i++ < max)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            i = 0
        }
    }

    fun someCode1() {
        //somecode
    }
    fun someCode2() {
        //somecode
    }
}
```